# How to manipulate the bound on the summation

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, combinatorics, summation, power-series

$$
B_n^{f^2}(x) = \sum_{k=1}^n\sum_{j=0}^{n-k} 2^{k-j} {j+k \choose j} \frac{d^j}{df^j}[f^k] B_{n,j+k}^f(x)
$$

I am looking to have the bounds switched, can someone show me exactly how this is done? Where can i read or find out more about doing this?

Comment: This is not an equation! An equation has a left hand side, an equal sign and a right hand side. Where did the factorials come from? The upper limit of the second sum, was there a $n$ in an earlier step? What is $B_{n,j}^f(x)$? What is the background of the whole thing? Just a guess Bezier splines?

Comment: @andre This is the bell polynomial of $f(x)^2$, i fixed it up a bit to where it looks a bit better

Comment: Could you give some references of the Bell polynomial of $g(x)$?

Comment: @andre The complete bell polynomial can be found here on wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_polynomials

Comment: There are $B_n(x)$ and $B_{n,k}(x)$ but neither $B_n^{f^2}(x)$ nor $B_{n,k}^f(x)$ on wikipedia. What is the definition of these last two functions?

Comment: @andre The definition of $B_n^{f^2}(x)$ is defined above, B_{n,k}^f(x) is defined on the wikipedia, just make the $x_m = \frac{d^m}{dx^m}[f(x)]$

Comment: @andre The question can be answered without knowing the definition of $B^f_{n,j+k}$, as long as the summation shown makes any sense (that is, as long as $B^f_{n,j+k}$ is defined in each summand). And now someone has answered it.

Comment: @DavidK, well said, but I like to have a question first where everything is well defined.

Comment: @andre From the form of the question, I think we're supposed to assume everything that needs to be defined is well-defined. I suppose you mean you want to know explicitly what that definition is, not just to be told there is one. But sometimes giving less specific knowledge about a formula makes for a more powerful result. How useful would Fubini's Theorem be if all the proofs for it required first that the function in question had to be "well defined" in that sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The summation is over the green region in the diagram below. To interchange $j$ and $k$, just determine what the region looks like after swapping the axes (reflecting about a $45^\circ$ line). So $j$ runs from $0$ to $n-1$ and $k$ runs from $1$ to $n-j$.

$B_n^{f^2}(x) = \sum\limits_{j=0}^{n-1}{\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n-j}{\{...\}}}$

[image: Switching order of a double summation]